# self.presentingViewController broken on iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I'm experiencing something really weird :

Create an extremely basic single view project, and add a second view controller to the storyboard, along with a modal segue from the first to the second. Initiate the segue from the view controller and trigger it programmatically with `performSegueWithIdentifier:`.

In the `viewDidLoad` of the modally presented view controller, add this log :

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.presentingViewController);
```

Now run the app on **iOS 7**, you should get a log like this one :

```
<ViewController: 0x7fa8e9530080>
```

Which is just the reference of the initial view controller of the app, which presented the modal view controller.

Now run **the exact same thing** on **iOS 8**, and you will get :

```
(null)
```

What's going on here ? Is it a known issue ? Of course I'd expect the exact same behavior on both systems.

Comment: viewDidLoad should really be used for initialization, At this stage, there is not guarantee that the receiver's controllers view hierarchy has been placed in the navigation tree. If that is your intent, you should override viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.  Whilst it works in earlier versions, the docs clearly state that it should be used for additional initialization. It certainly sounds as though in iOS 8, the receiver's initialization is being performed earlier.

Comment: Well.. This makes sense.. I'll do some tests and let you know if you should turn your comment to an answer

Comment: @MDB983: turns out you're right, even in *viewWillAppear:* the presenting view controller is set. If you want to turn your comment to an answer, I'd be pleased to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks ... Formalizsed as answer.

viewDidLoad should really be used for initialization, At this stage, there is not guarantee that the receiver's controllers view hierarchy has been placed in the navigation tree. If that is your intent, you should override viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear. Whilst it works in earlier versions, the docs clearly state that it should be used for additional initialization. It certainly sounds as though in iOS 8, the receiver's initialization is being performed earlier